# Getting error: String reference not set to an instance of a String. Parameter name: s

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using this code to truncate datetime from my database into its year and time components. The variables YearOfRelease and Runtime contain datetime of the format       "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" It was working fine previously but its now giving the error:

**String reference not set to an instance of a String.
Parameter name: s**

It could only be something wrong in the DateTime.ParseExact function, could anyone please let me know why 'null' is suddenly causing this problem when previously it was working perfectly?

```
    DateTime dt2 = new DateTime();


    dt = DateTime.ParseExact(YearOfRelease, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss", null);

    Year = dt.Year.ToString();


    dt2 = DateTime.ParseExact(RunTime, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss", null);
    string hour = dt2.Hour.ToString();
    string min = dt2.Minute.ToString();

    Time = hour + ":" + min;
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The first parameter of [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) is a string parameter named 's'.

Therefore, it looks like YearOfRelease or RunTime is null in your program.  Make sure those are set before you call DateTime.ParseExact.

Comment: You mean in the database? Nope, they are not null, I just checked

Comment: Thanks, I rechecked, there was something wrong in my c# code, the variables weren't getting the correct values.